# Easiest way to evaluate constant SVal

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I'm trying to find the easiest way to get the value in a constant SVal. Currently I am doing something along the lines of:

```
SVal s = ...; // Get valid SVal from somewhere
int64_t val = 0; // Will hold value of SVal

if (!s.isUnknownOrUndef() && s.isConstant()) {
    switch (s.getBaseKind()) {
        case NonLocKind: {
            s_val = s.getAs<nonloc::ConcreteInt>().getValue();
            val = s_val.getValue().getExtValue();
         }
         // handle other cases
         //   ...
    }
}

llvm::outs() << "Value is " << val << "\n";
```

I didn't show it here but there more code checking that values are known, checking the sign and type of constants, etc. I feel like there is probably a better way.

Comment: Please update your post with the declaration or definition of `SVal`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews [`SVal`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ento_1_1SVal.html) comes from the `clang-static-analyzer`